# Android, threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d4bb20)

Tags: android, json, multithreading, httprequest, httpresponse

So my application makes http request calls to an API and receives a response back. My application turns the response into JSON and I parse through it. The issue I'm having is this?

```
 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d4bb20)
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.stevefoo.wrestt, PID: 30650
 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stevefoo.wrestt/com.example.stevefoo.wrestt.Admin.AdminUserBrowse}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime: at com.example.stevefoo.wrestt.Admin.AdminUserBrowse.retrieveUsers(AdminUserBrowse.java:70)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at com.example.stevefoo.wrestt.Admin.AdminUserBrowse.onCreate(AdminUserBrowse.java:42)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
 E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 E/AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I realized I'm getting a null pointer exception on the retrieveUser method. When I carefully inspected the JSON response being used by retrieveUser I realized that I'm not getting a full JSON response back. It's only giving me a partial JSON response back. If I use http pie to retrieve the JSON response from the server I get the full thing so the problem isn't the server. It's the call I'm making. The method being used to make the call is inside the CustomThread Callable, executeHttpGet:

```
 /** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

/** Single instance of our HttpClient */
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

/**
 * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object
 * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
 */
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}

public static String CustomThreadHttpGet(final String url, final String token){

        String result = null;
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    Future<String> future = service.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(url, token);
            response = response.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            return response;
        }
    });

    try {
        // get() waits for the task to finish and then gets the result
        result = future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // thrown if task was interrupted before completion
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // thrown if the task threw an execption while executing
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}

public static String executeHttpGet(String url, String token) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        //creates http client to make request
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        //Stream reader deciphers the response
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason this call is making the thread exit early before it can get the full JSON response, or at least I think that's what happening. The method actually works fine as long the JSON response is under 4000 characters, however if it goes over that it begins to only give me partial JSON responses back. Any insight for my dilemma would be appreciated.